# awatch does not stop on specified address

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gdb, watch

I understand that the awatch command in GDB breaks when expresssion is read/written. However, why is it that when I set awatch command to an address of my structure pointer, it only stopped once. Below is a screenshot of my GDB and a code snippet. Please advice. Thank you.

[image]

Testing.c

```
College_Record *college = NULL;
college = malloc(sizeof(College_Record));
printf("college %p\n", college);
free(college);
printf("college %p\n", college);
college = NULL;
printf("college %p\n", college);

printf("***************************\n");
printf("\tDONE OKAY\n");
printf("***************************\n");

return 0;
```

Testing.h

```
  typedef struct {
    int college_id;
    char school[20];
} College_Record;
```

Comment: You've already derefed the pointer, so awatch 0x602010 might be it.  Or, awatch -l 0x602010.  The easy way was probably awatch -l *college

Comment: awatch -l *college says "A syntax error in expression, near `{...} *) 0x0000000000602010'." Also, awatch 0x602010 or awatch -l 0x602010 says "Cannot watch constant value `0x602010'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample program:

```
struct college {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct college college_glob;

struct college *college;

void
setwatch(void)
{

    college = &college_glob;
}

void
brkgdb(void)
{
}

int
main(void)
{

    setwatch();
    brkgdb();

    return college_glob.x;
}
```

Here's the gdb session:

```
> gdb /tmp/watch
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.9.1-19.fc22
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /tmp/watch...done.
(gdb) b brkgdb
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40050c: file /tmp/watch.c, line 20.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/watch 

Breakpoint 1, brkgdb () at /tmp/watch.c:20
20  }
(gdb) awatch *college
Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: *college
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: *college

Value = {x = 0, y = 0}
Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: *college

Value = {x = 0, y = 0}
main () at /tmp/watch.c:30
30  }
(gdb) list
25  
26      setwatch();
27      brkgdb();
28  
29      return college_glob.x;
30  }
(gdb) q
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 15761] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Comment: Thank you for this sample program.

Comment: @Marss You're welcome.  I do this whenever I need to test a feature of something I've never used (e.g. language construct, debug cmd, library call, etc.).  Create a small test/diagnostic program that _just_ does that one thing.  What I created what _guaranteed_ to reference the glob.  In your program, you had two questions: (1) does awatch work? (2) does program actually reference the memory?  The test program only had (1) to contend with (by design).  My dirty little secret:  Even afterwards, I had to try _several_ [not shown ;-)] variants of awatch to find _the_ one.